# Django Querying Datetimes Incorrectly?

Tags: python, django, datetime

Basically I have two datetimes, one from each model. According to python, the datetimes are equal. When I try to query one type of object with the other's datetime, no results are returned. However when I try to do the reverse and query the other by the first's datetime, a result is returned. The examples below should clarify what is wrong.

My models look like this (abbreviated):

```
class Shift(models.Model):
    normalized_start = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class ScheduledShift(models.Model):
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

The unexpected behavior of not returning a result:

```
>>> shift = m.Shift.objects.get(pk=796)
>>> scheduled_shift = m.ScheduledShift.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> shift.normalized_start == scheduled_shift.start_datetime
True
>>> shift.normalized_start, scheduled_shift.start_datetime
(datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 4, 23, 15), datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 4, 23, 15))
>>> m.ScheduledShift.objects.filter(start_datetime=shift.normalized_start)
[]
```

However, when I query the other model (this is what should have happened in the last example)...

```
>>> m.Shift.objects.filter(normalized_start=scheduled_shift.start_datetime)
[<Shift 796>]
```

I am using SQLite if it makes any difference.

Comment: Is there any major difference in the queries being generated?  Try importing django.db.connection and after each query call connection.queries[-1:]

Comment: 'SELECT "app_scheduledshift"."id", [...] FROM "app_scheduledshift" WHERE "app_scheduledshift"."start_datetime" = 2011-01-04 23:15:00  LIMIT 21'

Comment: 'SELECT "app_shift"."id", [...] FROM "app_shift" WHERE "app_shift"."normalized_start" = 2011-01-04 23:15:00  LIMIT 21'

Comment: What is the result if you try both queries in the sqlite prompt?

Comment: Curiously enough, a syntax error near '23'. When I put quotes around the datetimes, the same results are returned as in the example. HOWEVER, when I select each datetime in sqlite, one is '2011-01-04 23:15:00' and the other is '2011-01-04 23:15:00+00:00'. This is strange since I am running the same normalization on each dt before I store it in the database, namely dt.replace(second=0, microsecond=0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the SQL generating the Tables themselves.  Based on the comments on your question, It sounds like SQLite is using different datatypes to store the null vs. non-null data, and this is causing a formatting error.

Comment: Any idea how to fix this behavior? that is what I'm really looking for.

Comment: To be honest, I cannot confirm that this is the root cause of your behavior, as I don't have a django instance I can experiment with at the moment.  If looking at the SQL produced by this 'django-admin.py sql' indicates differenting datatypes is the root cause, mayhap create ScheduledShift with start_time=models.DateTimeField(null=True)?